# Bash script output file not readable

Tags: linux, bash, authentication, ssh, command

I'm new to bash scripting. I just typed a script to check whether there is a user in a remote server and print the IP address of the remote servers where the user exists in a file called exist.txt.

The output of the command "cat exist.txt" shows me an ip address, which I expected to be the output.

`[root@controlnode script]# cat exist.txt`

`10.52.85.214`

but when I execute the command,

`` for i in `cat exist.txt` ; do ssh a@$i; done ``

I get the error ": **Name or service not knownname 10.52.85.214"**

But manually I can ssh to the server 10.52.85.214 and it is working fine. Can someone help me how to solve this issue. I think there is a problem with the file that is generated from the script. (exist.txt)

The script is as below

```
#!/bin/bash
pass=XXXXXXX
loginuser=a
testuser=jose

#Check whether the user exsists in the remove server and collect a list of servers where the user is available
> exist.txt
> non_exist.txt
for server in `cat serverlist`
do
        echo "Checking server" $server
        sshpass -p$pass ssh -t $loginuser@$server ' if [[ $(getent passwd' "$testuser"') ]];  then echo `hostname -I`; fi ' >> exist.txt
        sshpass -p$pass ssh -t $loginuser@$server ' if ! [[ $(getent passwd' "$testuser"') ]];  then echo `hostname -I`; fi ' >> non_exist.txt
        echo "Server $server Checked"
        echo ".........................................................................................................................................."
        echo " "

done
```

Comment: Don't read lines with for. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#pf1

Comment: There could be DOS line endings in the file? Check the line separators in your input file.

Comment: Hi @Poshi Got it fixed. used dos2unix exist.txt. Thank you :)